# Mule Server Error: com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException: org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException

Tags: mule, mule-studio

My Mule Application works well with an Integrated Mule Server in the localmachine. When i deployed it to the standalone Server in different machine, it is throwing the following error while invoking the flow:

```
ERROR 2015-02-13 18:05:55,657 [[OrderFull-v201502131805].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException: org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException (java.lang.RuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. zip file closed (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  java.util.zip.ZipFile:632 (null)
2. Unknown component type: EXT_XML_WRITER (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  org.jetel.component.ComponentFactory:113 (null)
3. null (org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException)
  org.jetel.graph.TransformationGraphXMLReaderWriter:927 (null)
4. null (org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException)
  org.jetel.graph.TransformationGraphXMLReaderWriter:927 (null)
5. org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.graphfactory.DocumentCloverGraphFactoryImpl:59 (null)
6. com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException: org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.graphprovider.PoolGraphProvider:109 (null)
7. com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException: org.jetel.exception.XMLConfigurationException (java.lang.RuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:632)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:303)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:226)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Where to place the grf file in the server machine. Do i need to change the xsd and json file path entries in the grf file??

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's a well-known issue that has been fixed in Mule 3.4.0 RC4.

See: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6778